# more centered distribtution

Tags: distributions

In the below plot, I plot density (estimated) of two distributions. You can see that the treatment is more centered around origin which is the desired outcome. Is there a way to quantify this (other than the mean and variance)? Or does that question even make sense?

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Try employing the Kolmogorov–Smirnov statistic between the two cumulative distributions. To quote [from Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov%E2%80%93Smirnov_test):

> The two-sample K–S test is one of the most useful and general nonparametric methods for comparing two samples, as it is sensitive to differences in both location and shape of the empirical cumulative distribution functions of the two samples.

And further:

> The Kolmogorov–Smirnov test can be modified to serve as a goodness of fit test. In the special case of testing for normality of the distribution, samples are standardized and compared with a standard normal distribution. This is equivalent to setting the mean and variance of the reference distribution equal to the sample estimates, and it is known that using these to define the specific reference distribution changes the null distribution of the test statistic (see Test with estimated parameters). Various studies have found that, even in this corrected form, the test is less powerful for testing normality than the Shapiro–Wilk test or Anderson–Darling test.[1] However, these other tests have their own disadvantages. For instance the Shapiro–Wilk test is known not to work well in samples with many identical values.

Comment: How does this help say which is more concentrated around 0?